# Winsock socket doesn't recveive packet cpp

Tags: c++, udp, winsock2

I have a client that waits for the server to send a broadcast to a specific port and then return a message.

I can see the packet in Wireshark, but my application doesn't catch it.

[image: packet on Wireshark]

Here is the function that catches the packet. (getPrivateIP works)

```
uint32_t findMastersIP()
{
    sockaddr_in recvAddr{};
    sockaddr_in sendAddr{};

    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
        std::cout << "Socket error <" << WSAGetLastError() << ">" << std::endl;
    
    int opt;

    std::string message, response;
    char* buf = new char[65536];
    int fromlen;

    recvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = getPrivateIP();
    recvAddr.sin_port = htons(667);
    recvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    fromlen = sizeof(recvAddr);

    opt = 1;
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&opt, sizeof(opt))<0)
        std::cout << "Sockopt error <" << WSAGetLastError() << ">" << std::endl;

    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (const char*)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0)
        std::cout << "Sockopt error <" << WSAGetLastError() << ">" << std::endl;

    if(bind(s, (sockaddr*)&recvAddr, sizeof recvAddr) < 0)
        std::cout << "Bind error <" << WSAGetLastError() << ">" << std::endl;

    /*fixed messages for my "protocol"*/
    message = "What is your IP?";
    response = "My IP";

    /*wait for the master to ask me to connect*/
    do {
        ZeroMemory(buf, 65536);
        if(recvfrom(s, buf, 65536, 0, (sockaddr*)&recvAddr, &fromlen) <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Recieve error <" << WSAGetLastError() << ">" << std::endl;
            goto errorLable;
        }
        std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    } while (!std::string(buf)._Equal(message));

    if(sendto(s, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0, (sockaddr*)&recvAddr, sizeof(recvAddr)) <= 0)
        std::cout << "Send error <" << WSAGetLastError() << ">" << std::endl;


errorLable:
    delete[] buf;
    closesocket(s);
    return recvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr;
}
```

The weird thing is that it works when the server and the client are on the same computer, but not when they are on two different computers.

Does someone know what could cause that? And how to fix it?

Comment: Tactical note: If you move the `do`/`while` loop and the subsequent `if` to a function and `return` from the function when you get an error or the message, you won't have to waste time fighting over the `goto` statement during code review.

Comment: `recvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = getPrivateIP();` looks like you are only accepting messages from whatever `getPrivateIP` returns. Since I don't know what it returns, I can't be sure if this is what you want or not, but if it's not, you'll get the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: It returns my ip, "10.0.0.8", will it not accept broadcast messages?

Comment: I'm weak on broadcast and never tried to bind a broadcast message listener to a single sender so I might be dead wrong, but typically if you bind to a specific address, you only accept messages from that address.  If you don't care who is sending the message you use `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: @LeoSegol Unrelated to your problem: You don't need `SO_BROADCAST` to *receive* broadcasts, only to *send* them. Your loop is not resetting `fromlen` on each iteration before calling `recvfrom()`. `recvfrom()` returning 0 is not an error condition. `buf` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, unless the sender is sending null-terminated data, use the return value of `recvfrom()` to know `buf`'s actual length. `std::string` doesn't have an `_Equal()` method, use its `operator==` or `compare()` method instead. And you should use `fromlen` instead of `sizeof(recvAddr)` when calling `sendto(

Comment: @LeoSegol Do you have multiple NICs installed, by chance? If so, how does `GetPrivateIP()` know which NIC's IP to return? I think user4581301 is on to something. You are likely listening on a NIC that doesn't receive the broadcast.

Comment: @user4581301 Even after changing the address to INADDR_ANY I still don't get the packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the firewall blocked my program in private networks for some reason. I have now enabled the program and it works perfectly.

Comment: For my general knowledge, does it work with the firewall configuration after the firewall configuration with `recvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = getPrivateIP();`? If I ever find myself having to do this it'd be nice to know if the bound address is handled differently.

Comment: @ user4581301 I'm not sure I understood your question. I use `getPrivateIP()` and not `INADDR_ANY` and it works just fine.

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you. Quite unexpected.